# Countable refinement of intersections in $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So here’s a fairly elementary problem I came across but which I have trouble with solving: suppose $\mathcal{C} \subset P(\mathbb{N})$. Prove there is a countable $\mathcal{C}_0 \subset \mathcal{C}$ such that
$$\cap_{A \in \mathcal{C}}A=\cap_{A \in \mathcal{C_0}}A.$$
I think one needs to reason by contradiction and if this is not the case $\mathbb{N}$ would not be countable, but I can’t really make it precise. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $D:=\{\mathbb N-A\mid A\in C\}$. Notice that your problem is equivalent to proving that there is a countable $D_0\subseteq D$ such that
$$\bigcup_{B\in D_0}B=\bigcup_{B\in D}B.$$
Can you construct such $D_0$?